# How do I serialize a LabeledPoint RDD in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm getting an error when using PySpark's saveAsHadoopFile() and I get the same error when using saveAsSequenceFile(). I need to save an RDD of (key,val) where the key is a string and val is a LabeledPoint RDD (label, SparseVector). The error is shown below. Googling several sources it seems that I should be able to do this within an IPython notebook. I need to serialize this large RDD so I can process it in Java because some of Spark's MLLib functionality is not available for python yet. According to this [post](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/17/spark-1-1-bringing-hadoop-inputoutput-formats-to-pyspark.html) this should be doable.

Looking at this [page](https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/branch-1.3/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F) I see:

```
_picklable_classes = [
    'LinkedList',
    'SparseVector',
    'DenseVector',
    'DenseMatrix',
    'Rating',
    'LabeledPoint',
]
```

so I really have no clue why I'm getting this error.

> Code: 
>       labeledDataRDD.saveAsSequenceFile('/tmp/pysequencefile/')
>
> Error:
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsSequenceFile.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 527.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 527.0 (TID 1454, localhost): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)

Edit: I found this:

```
public class More ...ClassDictConstructor implements IObjectConstructor     {
12
13  String module;
14  String name;
15
16  public More ...ClassDictConstructor(String module, String name) {
17      this.module = module;
18      this.name = name;
19  }
20
21  public Object More ...construct(Object[] args) {
22      if (args.length > 0)
23          throw new PickleException("expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for "+module+"."+name+")");
24      return new ClassDict(module, name);
25  }
26}
```

I'm NOT using the construct() method above directly.. so I don't know why the saveAs.. methods that I tried pass it arguments when it want none.

Edit 2: following zero323 suggestion (Thank you) worked with a small glitch. I get an error (see below) when I tried what zero323 wrote. However, when I derive a simpler RDD it works and saves this simpler one to a directory of .parquet files (breaks it up to several .parquet files). The simpler RDD is as follows:

```
simplerRDD = labeledDataRDD.map(lambda (k,v): (v.label, v.features))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(simplerRDD, ("k", "v")).write.parquet("labeledData_parquet_file")
```

Error when trying to save labeledDataRDD:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _infer_schema(row)
    831         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
    832 
--> 833     fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]
    834     return StructType(fields)
    835 

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _infer_type(obj)
    808             return _infer_schema(obj)
    809         except TypeError:
--> 810             raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
    811 
    812 

TypeError: not supported type: <type 'numpy.unicode_'>
```

Comment: What functionality isn't provided to python yet?

Comment: take a look [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html#svd-example). I think they will add this in Spark 1.6. I'm using the very recent Spark 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is not pickling itself. If it was you wouldn't see `net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException`. If you take a look at the [`saveAsSequenceFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.saveAsSequenceFile) documentation you'll see that it requires two steps:

> 1. Pyrolite is used to convert pickled Python RDD into RDD of Java objects.
> 2. Keys and values of this Java RDD are converted to Writables and written out.

You program fails at the first step but even if it didn't I am not exactly sure what would be an expected Java object and how to read it back.

Instead of playing with sequence files I would simply write data as a Parquet file:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

rdd = sc.parallelize([
   ("foo", LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])),
   ("bar", LabeledPoint(2.0, [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]))])

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ("k", "v")).write.parquet("a_parquet_file")
```

read it back and convert:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val rdd: RDD[(String, LabeledPoint)] = sqlContext.read.parquet("a_parquet_file")
  .select($"k", $"v.label", $"v.features")
  .map{case Row(k: String, label: Double, features: Vector) =>
    (k, LabeledPoint(label, features))}

rdd.sortBy(_._1, false).take(2)

// Array[(String, org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint)] = 
//  Array((foo,(1.0,[1.0,2.0,3.0])), (bar,(2.0,[4.0,5.0,6.0])))
```

or if you prefer more Java-like approach:

```scala
def rowToKeyLabeledPointPair(r: Row): Tuple2[String, LabeledPoint] = {
  // Vector -> org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
  Tuple2(r.getString(0), LabeledPoint(r.getDouble(1), r.getAs[Vector](2)))
}

sqlContext.read.parquet("a_parquet_file")
  .select($"k", $"v.label", $"v.features")
  .map(rowToKeyLabeledPointPair)
```

**Edit**

Generally speaking NumPy types are not supported as a standalone values in Spark SQL. If you have Numpy types in a RDD you have convert these to standard Python types first:

```
tmp = rdd.map(lambda kv: (str(kv[0]), kv[1]))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(tmp, ("k", "v")).write.parquet("a_parquet_file")
```

Comment: you gave Scala code that i'm struggling to replicate in Java... I'm trying to read the dataFrame on the java side from the parquet file(s).  ` DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().parquet("labeledData_parquet_file"); JavaRDD<Vector> rows = df.toJavaRDD().map(**what goes here?**);`. Vector is an mllib Vector. The issue is that the dataFrame contain a sql Row NOT an mllib Vector, and I need an JavaRDD of (double label,SparseVector).

Comment: Row provides a large set of typed getter methods. You'll can use `getDouble`, `getString` for key and label, and `getAs` for vector.